# Heavy Static Coming From Speakers

Tags: 16.04, sound, speakers

I have a dual boot system with with ubuntu 16.04 LTS and windows.
Everything was fine until yesterday. Whenever I play any music, video from internet or even some system sounds come, they have a very high static and the sound is also very distorted. Naturally i checked my speakers but they work just fine on windows or when i connect them them to phone. SO how to fix this plz help. Also i download an app named recordmydesktop from software center and then the problem started. Since then i have removed it to see if it reverts but no and the problem still persists. PLZ FASt

Answer (score 0):

try going into alsamixer and adjusting the mic boost slider on the capture screen.

open a terminal and type `alsamixer` then hit "f4" for the capture screen. then use the down arrow to adjust. hit esc to exit the mixer.

if you would rather use the gui version type `alsamixergui` then check your levels.

cheers,